# Highcharts line chart strange issue

Tags: highcharts

HI pls find the below fiddle where the highcharts doesnt draw the line when the points have same value. is this a bug or i am missing somethihg ? how can we resolve this ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthsvr82/m63L22wm/1/)

i have modified the code as below mentioned below and calling the applyGradient but still i dont see the line. I am not sure what is wrong with this code.

```
lineChartOptions: function (displayFormat) {
                    var self = this;
                    var data = this.getSeriesData(false);
                    var xCategories = _.range(1, data.length + 1);
                    var title = $('#coid_title').text();
                    var defaultColor = ['#0f477a'];
                    var dataSum = 0;
                    var yData = _.pluck(data, 'y');
                    for (var i = 0, len = yData.length; i < len; i++) {
                        dataSum += yData[i];
                    }

//                  Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(defaultColor, function (color) {
//                      return {
//                          radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
//                          stops: [
//                      [0, color],
//                      [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.0).get('rgb')] // darken
//                  ]
//                      };
//                  });

                    var applyGradient = function (color) {
                        return {
                            radialGradient: {
                                cx: 0.5,
                                cy: 0.3,
                                r: 0.7
                            },
                            stops: [
                                [0, color],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.0).get('rgb')]
                            ]
                        };
                    };

                    var options = {

                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'coid_graphicalChart',
                            type: 'line',
                            reflow : false,
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: ""
                            },
                            events: {
                                load: function (e) {
                                    var series = this.series[0];
                                    var pointData = series.data;
                                    var chart = series.chart;
                                    var legendTitle = self.currentGraphData;
                                    var $legend = $('.highcharts-legend');
                                    $legend.empty();

                                    var renderer = chart.renderer;
                                    var chartHeight = chart.chartHeight;
                                    var maxWidth = 324, wrappedHeight = 13, inc = 20,
                                    yt = 25,
                                    ixl = 5, yl = 50,
                                    cxl = ixl + 349, nxl = ixl + 25,
                                    ixr = 400, yr = yl,
                                    cxr = ixr + 354, nxr = ixr + 30;

                                    var leftColumnCnt = Cobalt.Search.Util.parseInt((pointData.length / 2) + (pointData.length % 2));

                                    var legendgroup = renderer.g().add();

                                    renderer.text(self.templates.lineChartLegend({ legendTitle: legendTitle }), ixl, yt).add(legendgroup);

                                    for (var i = 0; i < leftColumnCnt; i++) {
                                        var cnt = 0;
                                        renderer.text((i + 1) + ".", ixl, yl).add(legendgroup);
                                        var wrapped = self.drawText(legendgroup.element, pointData[i].name, nxl, yl, wrappedHeight, inc, maxWidth);

                                        if (self.displayFormat === self.constants.percentage) {
                                            cnt = renderer.text(Highcharts.numberFormat((pointData[i].y / series.options.dataSum) * 100) + '%', cxl, yl);

                                        } else {
                                            cnt = renderer.text(pointData[i].y, cxl, yl);
                                        }

                                        cnt.element.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'end');
                                        cnt.add(legendgroup);

                                        if (wrapped) {
                                            yl += inc + 27;
                                        } else {
                                            yl += inc;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    for (var i = leftColumnCnt, pointDataLength = pointData.length; i < pointDataLength; i++) {
                                        var cnt = 0;
                                        renderer.text((i + 1) + ".", ixr, yr).add(legendgroup);
                                        var wrapped = self.drawText(legendgroup.element, pointData[i].name, nxr, yr, wrappedHeight, inc, maxWidth);

                                        if (self.displayFormat === self.constants.percentage) {
                                            cnt = renderer.text(Highcharts.numberFormat((pointData[i].y / series.options.dataSum) * 100) + '%', cxr, yr);
                                        } else {
                                            cnt = renderer.text(pointData[i].y, cxr, yr);
                                        }

                                        cnt.element.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'end');
                                        cnt.add(legendgroup);

                                        if (wrapped) {
                                            yr += inc + 27;
                                        } else {
                                            yr += inc;
                                        }

                                    }

                                    $('g.highcharts-legend').append(legendgroup.element);
                                    $('.highcharts-background').attr('height', chartHeight + yl);
                                    chart.container.firstChild.setAttribute('height', chartHeight + yl);
                                    chart.container.style.height = chart.container.firstChild.style.height = chartHeight + yl + 'px';
                                    chart.container.parentElement.style.height = chartHeight + yl + 'px';
                                    self.hideChartTitle();
                                },
                                redraw: function (e) {
                                    this.series[0].chart = self.reCreateChart();
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        title: {
                            text: title
                        },

                        exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                        },

                        xAxis: {
                            categories: xCategories,
                            labels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '100%',
                                    color: '#000000'
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            labels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '100%',
                                    color: '#000000'
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        legend: {
                            enabled: true,
                            align: 'middle',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                            layout: 'vertical'
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            line: {
                                events: {
                                    legendItemClick: function () {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                },
                                lineWidth: 4,
                                marker: {
                                    radius: 8
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            useHTML: true,
                            enabled: true,
                            backgroundColor: '#fcfbdf',
                            borderColor: '#feda73'
                        },

                        series: [{
                            dataSum: dataSum,
                            animation: false,
                            data: data,
                            marker: {
                                fillColor: applyGradient(defaultColor)
                            }
                        }]

                    };

                    if (displayFormat === this.constants.percentage) {
                        options.tooltip.formatter = function () {
                            return self.templates.tooltip(self.tooltipFormatter(this.series.options.dataSum, this.key, this.y, displayFormat));
                        };
                    } else {
                        options.tooltip.formatter = function () {
                            return self.templates.tooltip(self.tooltipFormatter(this.series.options.dataSum, this.key, this.y, displayFormat));
                        };
                    }

                    return options;
                },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that for line charts where you have zero values or adjacent data points with the same value the only way to achieve a gradient is by applying the gradient to the markers themselves rather than the actual line.

It seems that this was/is a known `Highcharts` issue as can be seen [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2517), but the `markers` work around which I pulled from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/175/) can be viewed in the below snippet:

```js
$(function () {
    var colors = ['#4572A7',
        '#AA4643',
        '#89A54E',
        '#80699B',
        '#3D96AE',
        '#DB843D',
        '#92A8CD',
        '#A47D7C',
        '#B5CA92'];
    var applyGradient = function (color) {
        return {
            radialGradient: {
                cx: 0.5,
                cy: 0.3,
                r: 0.7
            },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')]
            ]
        };
    };

    // works if you comment this out.
    //colors = $.map(colors, applyGradient);

    $('#container').highcharts({
        colors: colors,
        title: {
            text: 'Points with zero value are not connected by line'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            offset: 0,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                connectNulls: true
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
        },
        series: [{
            data: [2, 10, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 30, 20],
            marker: {
                fillColor: applyGradient(colors[0])
            }
        }, {
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            marker: {
                fillColor: applyGradient(colors[1])
            }
        }, ]

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: this works but i have code something like this what do you suggest here ? [code](     var defaultColor = ['#0f477a'];
     var dataSum = 0;
     var yData = _.pluck(data, 'y');
     for (var i = 0, len = yData.length; i < len; i++) {
      dataSum += yData[i];
     }

     Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(defaultColor, function (color) {
      return {
       radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
       stops: [
                  [0, color],
                  [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(0.0).get('rgb')] // darken
              ]
      };
     });)[code]

Comment: @user3496151 It's almost impossible to understand the code in the comment. You should make an edit to your original posting and add the code that you wrote above. Then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: thanks i have updated the code and fiddle above can you help with the same issue using the above code ?

Comment: @user3496151 See my edited answer for a potential workaround.

Comment: thanks your code seems to work fine but when i use the same approach in my actual code that was edited it is still not showing the line between the points. Not sure what is wrong here

Comment: In your code try `fillColor: applyGradient(defaultColor[0])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68983/discussion-between-user3496151-and-aus-lacy).